# allow-intent links not opening externally

Tags: ios, cordova

I'm trying to specify which links in my Cordova app should open within the Cordova app and which should open externally. I'd like social media links to open externally, and also any link that ends with .pdf. My `config.xml` has the following rules:

```xml
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="https://my-domain.com/*.pdf" launch-external="yes" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" launch-external="yes" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://facebook.com/*" launch-external="yes" />
<allow-intent href="https://twitter.com/*" launch-external="yes" />
<allow-intent href="https://instagram.com/*" launch-external="yes" />
<allow-intent href="https://*.facebook.com/*" launch-external="yes" />
<allow-intent href="https://*.twitter.com/*" launch-external="yes" />
<allow-intent href="https://*.instagram.com/*" launch-external="yes" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<allow-navigation href="http://my-domain.com" />
```

From the examples I can find online, this config should cause the following behaviour:

1. An `a` link with `href="https://my-domain.com/profile"` should open within the app
2. An `a` link with `href="https://facebook.com/myPage"` should open externally, in whatever app the device has configured to open `facebook.com` links (so the official Facebook app or a web browser)
3. An `a` link with `href="https://my-domain.com/example.pdf"` should open externally, in whatever app the device has to configured to open PDF files.

However on iOS in all these examples, the links open within the Cordova browser. What am I doing wrong?